# Login Failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18456)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a new user on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which uses SQL Server Authentication.

However whatever username and password I choose, after attempting to connect with the credentials I just get the same error message. I am positive the username and password are correct as I just created them

[image]

Do I have to reinstall the program to get rid of this error or is there a workaround for this error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for additional messages that detail the reason for the login failure.

Comment: The SQL Error Log has more details, including a `State` value which tells you exactly what's failing.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of where these logs can be found as I have no idea, I'm new to SQL Server.

Comment: Top link in Google for "SQL Server error log" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: NIce one, found it thanks. I just disconnected and reconnected again and the error went away by magic.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new server you likely configured the auth mode as 'Windows', but what you need is 'mixed' allowing for both Windows users and Database users. Multiple ways to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I already did this